# In Android, why that sometimes UI manipulation still works but very laggy without using runOnUithread?

Tags: java, android

I just noticed that, I'm able to setVisibility the UI Element in android on a different thread from UI without running it in runOnUiThread but it is very very laggy. Are there any formal explanation for this ? I always thought that it is either works or not work at all

Here's a code inside runOnUiThread (MainActivity):

```
@Override
public void onDataWritten(final boolean success) {
    System.out.println("Written");
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            preferenceFragment.onWritten(success);
        }
    });
}
```

Here's the one outside runOnUiThread (MainActivity):

```
@Override
public void onDataWritten(final boolean success) {
    System.out.println("Written");
    preferenceFragment.onWritten(success);
}
```

Which will call a method (PreferenceFragment):

```
public void onWritten(boolean completed){
    if(completed){
        sendingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to trace the source, maybe ot use handler.post() to update the view

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about `setVisibility` and not `setVisible`. As @MickeyTin says you can update the view by posting to a `Handler` which will run the method on the UI thread. If you don't run the methods on the UI thread, you're not guaranteed time on the main thread and so the main (UI) thread will run for as long as it has something to do - then you might get time to run your method... It boggles me however why you don't get an exception when running methods outside the UI thread... could you post your code?

Comment: Yes it was setVisibility, not setVisible,  my bad, I posted the code for you :)